# Moving items in a listbox in c#

Tags: c#, listbox, swap

I am adding file names from a directory in a list box which I am able to add successfully.I then should be able to arrange the files in the list box  by selecting a particular item & then moving it up or down.

The below function is an attempt to move the file up. I am trying to copy entire listbox items to an object and selected listbox 
items to a different object.

Then if button is pressed the selected item should be swapped with the item above to it in the list.

I intend to change the new list and copy the items back to the original listbox.But I am unaware how to copy items from object back to the listbox

The below code does not work

```
private void plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        object[] items = new object[listBox1.Items.Count];

        listBox1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

        object[] selecteditems = new object[listBox1.SelectedItems.Count];

        listBox1.SelectedItems.CopyTo(selecteditems, 0);

        object[] selectedindices = new object[listBox1.SelectedItems.Count];

        listBox1.SelectedIndices.CopyTo(selectedindices, 0);



       // listBox1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0);

        int upper_index = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count;i++ )
        {
           if ((i == (int)selectedindices[i])&&(i!=0))
            {
                    object temp = items[i];
                    items[i] = items[i - 1];
                    items[i - 1] = temp;
           }
        }








    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first sight it should not work because you're creating a new a list and not changing the actual `DataSource` for the `ListBox`. You need to move the items inside the `DataSource` itself, or you need to perform all that actions on a separate list and at the end, set the `DataSource` again.

Comment: I intend to change the new list and copy the items back to the original listbox.But I am unaware how to copy items from object back to the listbox

Comment: @SudarshanTaparia Do you want a circular shift ? e.g. if the use selected the first item and clicked `Up`. What do you expect to happen ?

Comment: i would want the selected item to move up and and the item above to move down